# program ir receiver

Tags: c#, hook, infrared

I am thinking to buy an IR receiver for my HTPC.

I wonder if I can make a software for my IR Receiver myself.

How does ir receiver work on windows ?

I mean, if I install IR receiver driver and press a key on my remote controller, what happen? can I get pressed button in c# using hook? if I can catch pressed button, it would be fun to play with :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good place to start would be [WinLIRC](http://winlirc.sourceforge.net/).  I personally don't have any experience with IR remotes, but I suspect that any remote you use will be behind an abstraction layer.  Essentially, the key presses on the remote are indistinguishable from ordinary keyboard key presses.